# JavaFX FXML Scalable UI

Tags: java, wpf, javafx, fxml

Is it in any way possible to achive the same behaviour with JavaFx and Fxml, that I would get when using a ViewBox in WPF?

In WPFyou could design your UI in an, for example, 800x600 sized container. If you put this in a Viewbox, you can resize the Windows as you like, and the elements within will scale accordingly.

Seems to me like there is no such thing as a Viewbox in Fxml. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know what a ViewBox is, but take a look at some related questions on: [resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229149/javafx-automatic-resizing-and-button-padding), [scaling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling), [zooming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257887/java-zui-zoomable-user-interface) and [letterboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606162/javafx-fullscreen) and see if anything there is of use or similar to what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Also try this [scalable UI sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5603471).